# DataLakeServiceClient throws Type definition error: [simple type, class com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClient] while using Java SDK

Tags: azure-java-sdk, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying access ADLS using Java SDK.
following is the configuration that i am using to get DataLakeServiceClient.

```
import com.azure.core.http.HttpClient;
import com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;
import com.azure.storage.common.StorageSharedKeyCredential;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeDirectoryClient;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeFileClient;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeFileSystemClient;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeServiceClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.ListPathsOptions;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.PathAccessControl;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.PathAccessControlEntry;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.PathItem;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.PathPermissions;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.RolePermissions;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AdlsController {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @GetMapping("/getDataLakeServiceClient")
    public DataLakeServiceClient GetDataLakeServiceClient() {

        String endpoint = "https://" + env.getProperty("azure.storage.account-name") + ".dfs.core.windows.net";

        ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(env.getProperty("spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-id"))
                .clientSecret(env.getProperty("spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-secret"))
                .tenantId(env.getProperty("azure.activedirectory.tenant-id"))
                .build();

        DataLakeServiceClientBuilder builder = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder()
                .wiretap(true)
                .build();
        return builder.httpClient(client).credential(clientSecretCredential).endpoint(endpoint).buildClient();
    }
}
```

The pom.xml has following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-file-datalake</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>12.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core-http-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

On calling the controller the request is failing and I am getting following error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClient]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClient and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeServiceClient["httpPipeline"]->com.azure.core.http.HttpPipeline["httpClient"])
↵   at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:323)
↵   at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:287)
↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181)
↵   at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
↵   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
↵   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
↵   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:52)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:216)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
↵   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
↵   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
↵   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
↵   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
↵   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
↵   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
↵   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
↵   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
↵   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
↵   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
↵   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
↵   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
↵Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClient and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeServiceClient["httpPipeline"]->com.azure.core.http.HttpPipeline["httpClient"])
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1277)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1513)
↵   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1005)
↵   at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:317)
↵   ... 92 more
↵
```

In order to resolve this error i added following dependencies to to pom.xml but it does not seem to work

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core-http-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Can anyone help me out to solve this issue?

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/9403.

Comment: @JimXu Thank for the response. I tried after downgrading the version s of dependencies as mention in the git issue, but I am still not able to get it. i also tried using OkHttpAsyncHttpClientBuilder intead of NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder, but got the same error for OkHttpAsyncHttpClient.

Comment: Ok. I see. I will do some test.

Comment: Please check my test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, we can use the following version sdk in spring boot application access azure data lake gen2

```
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <azure.version>2.2.4</azure.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-file-datalake</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Code

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getFile() throws IOException {
        String clientId = "42e0d***********22d988c4";
        String secret = "Gbx2eK64************Ijoae:";
        String tenant = "e4c9ab4e-b*************0ba2a757fb";
        String endpoint="https://testadls05.blob.core.windows.net/";
        ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(secret)
                .tenantId(tenant)
                .build();
        DataLakeServiceClientBuilder builder = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder()
                .wiretap(true)
                .build();
        DataLakeServiceClient client = builder.httpClient(httpClient).credential(clientSecretCredential).endpoint(endpoint).buildClient();
        DataLakeFileSystemClient dataLakeFileSystemClient =client.getFileSystemClient("test");
        DataLakeFileClient fileClient =  dataLakeFileSystemClient.getFileClient("test.csv");
        int dataSize = (int) fileClient.getProperties().getFileSize();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(dataSize);
        fileClient.read(outputStream);
        String content =outputStream.toString();
        outputStream.close();
        return content;
```

[image]